# Comparision between vectors fails

Tags: octave

I am implementing the simplex algorithm for an university course.

The code works well, but when I'm testing with the provided test problem I do not get the right result.

One line in the code compares two vectors `pMinC` and `zeros(n,1)` where `n` is the dimension of `pMinC` to decide whether the result is optimal.

In the second iteration I get the vector `pMinC = [ 0.00000 4.00000 3.50000 -33.00000 -3.00000 0.00000 0.00000]` which is obviously bigger than zero, but the algorithm terminates.

The code looks like this:

```
while(done == false)
   % compute pMinC
   if (sum(pMinC > zeros(n,1)))
      % do stuff
   else
      done = true;
   endif
endwhile
```

Why does the comparison work first and then fails the second time?

Comment: you shouldn't ignore the "warning: using binary expansion"... Thus pMinC > zeros(n,1) is a matrix -> sum a vector. Use if (any (pMinC > zeros(1, n))

Comment: I removed the `optimisation` tag because it is unrelated to the question. Removed the `matlab` tag as well because this is an issue special to octave. Matlab would throw an `dimension mismatch`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are comparing a n*1 vector with a 1*n vector. In this case octave broadcasts the variable (similar to matlabs `bsxfun`) resulting in a matrix. The sum of a matrix is a vector.

Use `if any(pMinC>0)` to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The comparison is summing up the results of the logical tests, not the sum of the positive deviations.  Is that what you want?

```
>> sum(pMinC > zeros(1,7))

ans =

 2

>> pMinC > zeros(1,7)

ans =

 0     1     1     0     0     0     0

>>
```